# Mostrar Objeto JSON procedente de MongoDB

Tags: json, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, angular6

Tengo una problema para mostrar un array de un objeto JSON procedente de MongoDB. La petición Ajax funciona correctamente y los datos se muestran bien por la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema viene en la vista, cuando intento mostrar en el html y la clase del componente esos datos.

Aquí os dejo mi clase del componente FiveWordsComponent.ts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os dejo mi clase del componente FiveWordsComponent.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Hola @Jaime, en lugar de poner imágenes con el código, copia y pega tu código en formato texto para poder ayudarte mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que veo tendrías que guardar los datos así: `this.words= response.words.word[0].words;`. En cualquier caso te recomiendo que en la consola hagas console.log(JSON.stringify(response.words) y **pegues el texto** en la pregunta (Pulsa [edit] para añadir lo que creas conveniente)

Comment: Efectivamente, Pablo, era eso. Muchas gracias